# More than one form on same page focus on same input where before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem that  i have more than one forms on same page and i want to focus same input field where it has before submit the form but if i submit then focus lost from that place .
i am using more forms with same fields .like for sale item sales fields item name, item price ,item quantity when i change quantity then submit that form i want that after reload page focus remain on same quantity field 
[image]
these are two different form when i change qty of fist field then submit this form a i want that it will be focused same field after reload page
please help me if any.

Comment: Maintaining information after a page reload requires storage, such as with a cookie, local storage, or server-side. How have you attempted to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cache the focused input field each time you click on one using the JS sessionstorage API.

```
var els = $('input, select');
els.each(function(i){
    $(this).on('focus', function(){
        sessionStorage.setItem('focused', i);
    })
})
```

Then when the page reloads, fetch the entry from the sessionstorage and give focus to the same element.

```
$(function(){
    var index = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('focused'));
    var els = $('input, select');
    $(els[index]).focus();
})
```

A more robust solution would be to cache a unique id (if any) of the input field instead of the indexed number. This way you could attach a single event to the body, and listen for the focus.

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input, select', function(e){
    sessionStorage.setItem('focused', e.target.id);
});
```

And then fetch the cached id on page load

```
$(function(){
    var id = sessionStorage.getItem('focused');
    $('#'+id).focus();
})
```

Comment: As per the comment made by @isherwood

Comment: i cant understand that how can i cache the focused input field . will you explain it plz

Comment: thanks it has done but it has done but it is not working on select field here is also a select field in the form

Comment: @NadeemIjaz I have updated my answer to include select elements too.